# Time out issue in java

Tags: java, timeout

I have been running this code and it seems like it times out. I'm not sure how to fix it as it doesn't show me an actual error message or anything like that. The first block of code is the class that the methods in the demo are coming from, and it seems like all the methods that are being called for stringList are just not working. When I test the same thing with an int list it works fine.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> {
    
    private static class Node<E> {
        // Node Fields
        private E element; //data
        private Node<E> prev; //previous Node
        private Node<E> next; //next Node
        
        // Node Constructor
        public Node(E e, Node<E> p, Node<E> n) {
            this.element = e;
            this.prev = p;
            this.next = n;
        }
        
        // Node Methods
        public E getElement() {
            return element;
        }
        public Node<E> getPrev() {
            return this.prev;
        }
        public Node<E> getNext() {
            return this.next;
        }
        public void setPrev(Node<E> p) {
            this.prev = p;
        }
        public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
            this.next = n;
        }

    }
    
    // DLinkedList Fields
    private Node<E> header;
    private Node<E> trailer;
    int size;
    
    // DLinkedList Constructor
    public DoublyLinkedList() { 
        this.header = new Node<>(null, null, null);
        this.trailer = new Node<>(null, this.header, null);
        this.header.setNext(this.trailer);
    }
    
    // DLinkedList Methods
    public int size() {
        return this.size;
    }
    public E first() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.header.next.getElement();
    }
    public E last () {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.trailer.prev.getElement();
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }
    public void addFirst (E e) {
        addBetween(e, this.header, this.header.getNext());
    }
    public void addLast (E e) {
        addBetween(e, this.trailer.getPrev(), this.trailer);
    }
    private void addBetween(E e, Node<E> predecessor, Node<E> successor) {
        Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, predecessor, successor);
        predecessor.setNext(newest);
        successor.setPrev(newest);
        this.size++;
    }
    public E removeFirst() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.remove(header.getNext());
    }
    public E removeLast() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.remove(trailer.getPrev());
    }
    public E remove(Node<E> e) {
        e.next.setPrev(e.prev);
        e.prev.setNext(e.next);
        this.size--;
        return e.getElement();
    }
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
        Node<E> walk = this.header.next;
        while (walk != this.trailer) {
            sb.append(walk.element);
            if (walk.next != this.trailer)
                sb.append(", ");
            walk = walk.next;
        }
        sb.append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }
    //DONE
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        Node<E> pred = header;
        Node<E> succ = pred.getNext();
        int count = 0;
        while(succ != null) {
            if(count == index) addBetween(element, pred, succ);
            count++;
            pred = pred.getNext();
            succ = succ.getNext();
        }
    }
    //DONE
    public void add(E e) {
        add(size, e);
    }
    //DONE
    public void clear() {
        while(!isEmpty()) {
            removeFirst();
        }
    }
    
    public E get(int index) {
        if (isEmpty()) return null;
        Node<E> current = header;
        int count = 0;
        while(current != null) {
            if(count == index) return current.getElement();
            count++;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        if(isEmpty()) return null;
        Node<E> current = header;
        E returnVal = null;
        int count = 0;
        while(current != null) {
            if(count == index) {
                if(count == 0) {
                    returnVal = get(0);
                    removeFirst();
                    add(0, element);
                }
                else if(count == size) {
                    returnVal = get(size);
                    removeLast();
                    add(size, element);
                }
                else {
                    returnVal = get(index);
                    remove(current);
                    add(index, element);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

```
package labs;

public class DoublyLinkedListDemo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //testing methods on a String DoublyList
        DoublyLinkedList<String> stringList = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
        stringList.addFirst("Strawberry");
        stringList.addFirst("Banana");
        stringList.addFirst("Apple");
        stringList.set(0, stringList.get(1));
        System.out.println(stringList);
        stringList.add(1, "Pear");
        System.out.println(stringList);
        stringList.add("Blueberry");
        System.out.println(stringList);
        System.out.println(stringList.get(1));
        stringList.clear();
        System.out.println(stringList);
        System.out.println(stringList.set(0, stringList.get(1)));
        System.out.println(stringList.get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Java code doesn't decide to "time out".  Does it really terminate? The most likely explanation is that you've coded an infinite loop.  Time to figure out how to debug code.

Comment: Take a close look to your `set` method. Where is `current` set to `null`, so the loop will be exited?